# Mysql dump as small bulk insert

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, bulk-insert, dump

In `mysql` *(8.0)*, there is a table with over 10 million rows, I want to dump it as bulk insert sql.

I wish each insert sql contains maybe 1k or 10k rows, so that could execute the sql file quickly, overall.

So how to do such a dump ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `mysqldump` does by default, or at least with some option.  Look at the output to confirm.

It will build `INSERT` statements will hundreds or thousands of rows in each.  This is optimal.  (A single `INSERT` with 10M rows is probably not possible.)

Comment: @EricWang - seems like -opt or some subset of it invokes that.

Comment: I did more test, basically you're right, though the bulk size is about `5000`. I dumped 100k records, there are 20 `insert` statements. Wondering is there anyway to control the bulk size.

Comment: Yes, there is a setting.  But I would not change it.  The difference between 500 and 5K or 5K and 50K will probably be less than 1% in speed difference.  At some point (probably _before_ 100K, you will hit some "hard" limit.  (It may be `max_allowed_packet`.)

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump has a"WJERE" clause in which can specify which data or number you want

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000000" database table > yourdumplimited.sql
```

or you can LIMIT byy time

```
 --where "your_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30'"
```

You can divide your table into fragmentss which you need.

Comment: So, I just run the 2nd command `N` times with different params, to get `N` small sql files? That might work I guess.

Comment: as yuu don't declare how your table looks like, i gave you some examples hw you would get to do it, date columns is one otion most take thier id column for that an d you can use it as normal where clause , sp oyu can combine columns. you have to give it a try

Comment: You don't need to do the chunking; mysqldump will do it for you.